# Scope Probe Voltage Ratings

Tags: oscilloscope, safety

I am wondering what the voltage ratings on passive scope probes really mean.

Suppose there is an inductive spike that exceeds the rating.  Will this damage the probe?  Will it damage the scope?  Is it a safety hazard to the operator?

My current thinking is that the shunt capacitor in the probe might fail short-circuit, removing the attenuating properties of the probe, and then exposing the scope to the same problematic voltages.  If this is the case, then I would think the probe should be rated against the worst-case inductive spike (which is both large, and difficult to predict), unless the scope itself has some protective circuitry against those voltages (does it?).

Comment: Unlikely to "fail short" as such. Possible to arc over (during the spike itself) which will indeed pass on most of the spike voltage. Possible permanent damage in the form of finite resistance destroying the probe's accuracy.

Comment: The scope will have some ESD protection.

Comment: Consider joules and rms voltage effects on components